# Assembly Code only returns two of possible four values in comparison

Tags: c++, assembly, arm, stm32f4discovery

I am currently writing a Program that requires C++ and Arm Assembly language to be implemented. The C++ code uses functions from the assembly file to perform particular tasks on a STM32F4discovery board touchscreen. One of the particular functions is a function that returns what quadrant the user is touching currently, and we had to write that function in assembly. No matter what I do, this function always returns quadrant 1 or 3. I think I am having an issue with branching properly, as this is one of my weak points, but I do not know for sure. Here is the function in context of the C++ code:

```
//all of this is above main
extern "C" uint32_t getQuad(uint16_t, uint16_t);
TS_DISCO_F429ZI ts; //touch screen sensing object
TS_StateTypeDef TS_State;
//other code here
ts.GetState(&TS_State); 
uint16_t x = TS_State.X;
uint16_t y = TS_State.Y;
uint32_t quad = getQuad(x, y);
```

And here is the function in the assembly file

```
                AREA Program3_F20_Gibbs, CODE, READONLY
                GLOBAL getQuad
                ; uint32_t getQuad ( uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
getQuad         LDR R0, [R0]
                LDR R1, [R1]
                
                CMP R0, #120
                BLE TwoThree
                
                CMP R1, #160
                BLE Four
                MOV R0, #1
                BX LR
                
TwoThree        CMP R1, #160
                BLE Three
                MOV R0, #2
                BX LR
        
Four            MOV R0, #4
                BX LR
        
Three           MOV R0, #3
                BX LR
```

I should probably also note that this quadrant system follows an x/y coordinate system with a bit of difference. Quadrant one has x/y coordinates with x > 120 and y > 160, Quadrant two has x/y coordinates with x < 120 and y > 160, Quadrant three has x/y coordinates with x < 120 and y < 160, and Quadrant four has x/y coordinates with x > 120 and y < 160. If I need to give any more info, please let me know, and thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: `uint16_t` is not passed by reference, so your first two `ldr` instructions are already broken and should blow up with an exception. Just deleting those might make your code work.

Comment: Okay wow that's a good tip to note for future projects - it seems to still have a little trouble with quadrant 1, but I am currently looking into the logic of that. Thank you so much for the feedback! If you have time may I ask why we have to pass it by reference conceptually?

Comment: It is **not** passed by reference. Your code wrongly assumed it was and even that was implemented wrong - you'd want to use `LDRH` to load 16 bits.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for all the help again! Still new to the whole merging Arm and C++ stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get away without any (conditional) branch:

```
getQuad
    cmp     r0, #120
    adr     r12, %f1
    addls   r12, r12, #2
    cmp     r1, #160
    addls   r12, r12, #1

    ldrb    r0, [r12]
    bx      lr

1
    dcb 1, 4, 2, 3
```

You really don't need to write it in assembly:

```
static inline uint32_t getQuad(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
{
    static const uint8_t array[4] = {1, 4, 2, 3};
    uint8_t *pSrc = array;

    if (x <= 120) pSrc += 2;
    if (y <= 160) pSrc += 1;

    return (uint32_t) *pSrc;
}
```

It's a very short function, hence you better inline it, and put it in the header file.
The pesky function call overhead is gone then.

PS: `le` (less of equal) is for signed value. You should us `ls` (lower or same) instead. `le` works in this case, but if you are dealing with 32bit values, it could cause disastrous problems that are hard to debug.

Comment: this is a cortex-m not a cortex-a nor predecessors to the cortex-a's

Comment: try fixing the code, compiling and then disassembling to see, can still do it without the branches...

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems sound except for the fact there should be some `<=` type operations in the text:

> Quadrant one has x/y coordinates with x > 120 and y > 160, Quadrant two has x/y coordinates with x <= 120 and y > 160, Quadrant three has x/y coordinates with x <= 120 and y <= 160, and Quadrant four has x/y coordinates with x > 120 and y <= 160.

However, unless the calling convention is very strange, you probably *don't* want to be doing this at the start:

```
LDR R0, [R0]
LDR R1, [R1]
```

This is what you do if you're passing the *addresses* of variables and you want to dereference those addresses to get the values. Therefore you will be using the wrong values to figure out which quadrant you're in.